# Convert docx to html using mammoth and html to docx using html-docx-js by node js giving error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ms-word, converters, mammoth

last few days I am fetching problem with my project when I am converting docx to html and after edit the html with angular editor I am saving the html into docx file again. I am using the following npm module below for converting.

```
Convert docx to html:
var mammoth = require("mammoth");

Convert html to docx:
var htmlDocx = require('html-docx-js')
```

Both module is working fine but problem is, when I am converting any html to docx from my website and then trying to convert it into html again, it's giving the response below and do not providing any html as value.
[image]

Here is my complete nodejs API function below:

```
Docx to html:
exports.convertDocxToHtml = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  let url = 'https://teamee-drive-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/drive/untitle.docx';
  const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
  const result = await mammoth.convertToHtml({ buffer: Buffer.from(response.data, "utf-8") })

  // let url = 'src/controllers/drive/default.docx';
  // // let url = 'src/controllers/drive/Imran4.docx';
  // const result = await mammoth.convertToHtml({ path: url })
  console.log(result)

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: result.value,
    message: "Data loaded success!"
  });
});
```

```
Html to Docx:
exports.saveHtmlToDocx = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  let body = req.body
  // console.log(body)
  const htmlString = `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>${body.html}</body>
  </html>`
  const opt = {
    margin: {
      top: 100
    },
    orientation: 'landscape'
  }
  var converted = htmlDocx.asBlob(htmlString, opt);
  console.log(converted)

  const s3 = new AWS.S3()
  const param = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME + '/drive',
    Key: `${body.document_title}.docx`,
    Body: converted
  }
  let data =  await s3.upload(param).promise()

  const update = await DriveFile.updateOne(
    {_id:body.id},
    {$set:{
      url:data.Location,
      folderId:body.folderId,
      fileName:`${body.document_title}.docx`
    }}
  )
  if (!update) {
      return next(new AppError("Document update faile", 400))
  }
  
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: update,
    message: "Data save success!"
  });
});
```

mammoth converting to html perfectly when I am trying with Microsoft office file but problem is when I am trying with generated file from my website.

Comment: @jonsson Actually I know that, what you saying but I expecting a solution from some one who did fixed like this problem already. Thanks for your comment :)